# Why DIV changed by `outerHTML` remains unresponsive

Tags: javascript, ajax, outerhtml

When I click on element it fires up, but when clicking again on that one does nothing. Refreshing page and clicking again works (till clicking it again). Why?

When div is clicked AJAX passes it to PHP in `xmlhttp.send();`; "click" event is handled by `document.getElementById('b_'+countr).addEventListener("click", selectionMade);`.

I think it's related with document loading - I want to fire something that is changed by `outerHTML`; full code provided below:

```
// prepare clicable map
for (x = 1; x <= 16; x++) {
for (y = 1; y <= 16; y++) {
    (function prepareClickableMap() {
        var cords = x + "x" + y;
        var el = document.getElementById(cords);
        el.addEventListener("click", function (e) { B_modeWindow('1', cords) });
    })();
}
}

//passing selection
for (countr = 1; countr <= 256; countr++) {
    document.getElementById('b_'+countr).addEventListener("click", selectionMade);
}


var s;
function selectionMade(e) {
    selection = e.currentTarget.id.split("_"); 
    s = selection[1];
}

// pass edited map info
function B_modeWindow (id,XxY) {  
    if (s !== undefined) {    
        loading();

        var xmlhttp;
        var position = XxY;

        if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
            xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
        } else {
            xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
        }

        var xy = position.split("x"); 

        xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function() {
            if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200) {
                document.getElementById(XxY).outerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;  

                hideloading();
            }
        }

        xmlhttp.open("GET","processMapEdit.php?id="+id+"&x="+xy[0]+"&y="+xy[1]+"&s="+s,true);
        xmlhttp.send();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`innerHTML` and `outerHTML` completely destroy whatever is being changed, and replaces it with the new HTML. In particular this means any event listeners are destroyed, so you have to either not use `innerHTML`/`outerHTML`, or reapply the listeners afterward.

Side-note: Instead of attaching an event listener to every tile on the map, attach it to the map itself and use `event.target` to find which tile was clicked.

Comment: how to reapply the listeners? + is it somehow slower?

Comment: After setting `outerHTML`, add code to attach the event listeners.